Creating custom projection in pyproj
I'm working on program that converts WGS-84 (ITRF-2005) to local coordinate systems. I have file with transform parameters looking like:
#СК-63(С2) 0 0 0
<999632> +proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27.95 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-11057.628 +ellps=krass +nadgrids=C:\Windows\vitt21a.gsb +geoidgrids=C:\Windows\147258.gtx +no_defs <>

How can I add my custom file to pyproj, so it take parameters from it?
When I'm trying kinda this:
self.my_crs = "+init=system.crs:"
self.cs_out = self.my_crs + cs_epsg_selected
transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("EPSG:4326").to_3d(), CRS(self.cs_out).to_3d())

It gives me error:
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: +init=system.crs:999632 +type=crs: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: cannot expand +init=system.crs:999632 +type=crs)

Or
self.my_crs = "system.crs:"
self.cs_out = self.my_crs + self.cs_epsg_selected
transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("EPSG:4326").to_3d(), CRS(f"EPSG:{cs_epsg_selected}).to_3d())

Result:
pyproj.exceptions.CRSError: Invalid projection: EPSG:999632: (Internal Proj Error: proj_create: crs not found)

And I can uderstand why, how can I fix it?
I undetstand that EPSG:4326 not ITRF2005, it will be edited soon, but for now, how can I add custom projections from file?


how can I add custom projections from file?

Currently, the database is how the CRS are looked up on PROJ. PROJ provides some capability to add them: https://github.com/OSGeo/PROJ/pull/2577
If I were to have my own set of custom CRS, I would have a static dictionary of projections and name the keys for lookup.
CUSTOM_CRS = {
    999632: "+proj=tmerc +lat_0=0 +lon_0=27.95 +k=1 +x_0=2250000 +y_0=-11057.628 +ellps=krass +nadgrids=vitt21a.gsb +geoidgrids=147258.gtx +no_defs"
}


self.cs_out = CUSTOM_CRS[cs_epsg_selected]
transformer_3d = Transformer.from_crs(CRS("EPSG:4326").to_3d(), CRS(self.cs_out).to_3d())

